# How to enable CXX11 support for Eigen3 on MSVC with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, eigen

I want to compile a executable that uses Eigen3 as the math backend, i would like to install Eigen with the `FetchContent` cmake module.
In the past i have used Eigen with `find_package` and specifically used `Eigen::Vector<type, size>` alias for `Matrix<type, size, 1>`.

But this time this fails, when i want to compile i get the following error message:

`error C2039: "Vector" is not a member of "Eigen"`

i guess it has to do with the C++ Version that Eigen is compiled with. I tried a lot of stuff like

`target_compile_features(eigen INTERFACE cxx_std_11)`

`set_target_properties(eigen PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 11)`

i also tried to tell cmake via the cl:

`cmake.exe -S . -B build -DEIGEN_TEST_CUSTOM_CXX_FLAGS="/std:cxx11"

But i always get the same output:

[image]

i am using msvc2022 and invoke cmake with `-T v142` if thats important.

the strange part is that when invoking cmake with `-DEIGEN_TEST_CXX11=ON` the following output is produced:

[image]

Here are the relevant CMakeLists.txt parts:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

# Project configuration
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
project( MyProject
  VERSION 0.1
  DESCRIPTION ""
  LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)    # doesnt work before msvc 2019
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# Eigen
#---------------------------------------
FetchContent_Declare(
  Eigen
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen.git
  GIT_TAG 3.3.9
  GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
  GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
  )

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(Eigen)

set_target_properties(eigen PROPERTIES
  CXX_STANDARD 11
  )

target_compile_features(eigen INTERFACE cxx_std_11)

# App
#---------------------------------------

add_executable(myexe main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myexe eigen)
install(TARGETS myexe)
```

Here is main.cpp

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main()
{
    Eigen::Vector<float, 3> v;
}
```

and here my call to cmake.exe

```
cmake.exe \
    -S . \
    -B build \
    -G "Visual Studio 17 2022"\
    -T v142 \
    -A x64 \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=D:/Program/\
    -DEIGEN_TEST_CXX11=ON \
    -DEIGEN_TEST_CUSTOM_CXX_FLAGS="/std:cxx11" \
&& cmake.exe \
    --build build \
    --target install \
    --config Release
```

Any suggestions are appreciated as i have no clue whats going on.

Thanks!

Edit:

well, seems to be a bug with Eigen <3.4 as changing `GIT_TAG 3.3.9` to  `GIT_TAG 3.4.0` solves the issue.

Comment: Visual Studio 2022 should default above c++11. In 2019 which I use it defaults to c++14. I don't have 2022 to test. I can't use it in production yet because a plugin that I use will require me to purchase a new license to support the new IDE.

Comment: Does adding `/Zc:__cplusplus` as an option to msvc solve the issue?